# What apps are there for questionnaires?

Tags: webapp-rec

I know Google docs has forms where I can create basic questionnaires, but I really need a site that lets me have more control over the layout of the questions. So what other web apps are there for creating forms that allow embedding images with the questions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[JotForm](http://www.jotform.com) is probably the best tool to create questionnaires quickly. I am biased since I developed the product, or at least the original version. But I will try to provide my reasons as objectively as possible.

1. Unlike Google Forms and the other products listed on this thread, JotForm does not add "Powered by" or "Report Abuse" links to your forms.
2. You have total control over the design of the forms and you can create great looking forms in minutes. You can choose from various themes or change design elements on the form builder. But in addition to all these, **JotForm also provides full form source code**. This means, even if you have a tiny little bit of hing that is bothering you but you can open the form on your favorite HTML editor and change it.
3. JotForm has over 40 form field types. Pretty much anything you might need for a questionnaire we have it. **And yes, you can insert images to your forms.**
4. You can section your questionnaire into multiple parts using heading, page breaks or a unique feature we have called FormCollapse, which allows you to hide part of the form and let users unhide them when needed.
5. JotForm conditional fields are great if you need to have any kind logic in your forms.
6. You can setup emails so that both you and the person who fills the form can receive emails.
7. You can get results in Excel or create reports with great looking charts.
8. Completely Free if you receive less than 100 submission per month. Unlike other tools all features are available on the free edition. There are no limits on number of forms, form fields or reports you can have on the free edition.

Please give it a try. You can try it without creating an account. If you have any questions, please let me know and I'd be happy to provide more details.

Comment: Excellent website, and very nicely detailed answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

[SurveyMonkey](http://www.surveymonkey.com) is one. I have used this for years and found it very well done and easy to use.

Answer (score 7):

[Wufoo](http://www.wufoo.com) is a really neat web form builder that could be used to construct a questionnaire. You can set up processing rules, email auto-responders etc and generate some pretty nifty reports from the data.  You can grab the code and embed the form directly into your website as well.

Comment: This is the closest to what I was looking for. It looked perfect, but it doesn't let me insert images.

Comment: Sorry I've changed my accepted answer because JotForm does let me insert my own images for the questionnaire. It gives far more control over the types of inputs on the questionnaire.

Comment: via @Chris Coyier . Wufoo does allow you to insert images. Most of the fields allow HTML in them. You'd just need to host the images somewhere you could link to them.

Answer (score 2):

[Polldaddy](http://www.Polldaddy.com/) is another one (has an iPad app too for viewing results)

It supports **images** and **video** too which I believe @Bernhard was specifically hoping for.

Comment: Polldaddy is great. It has a nice clean and customizable layout and give you a lot of options to design the survey. The statistics for the result are also nice.

Answer (score 1):

[Zoomerang](http://zoomerang.com/) is one.

Answer (score 0):

[surveygizmo](http://www.surveygizmo.com/)

They have a free trial.  I've used it before and it worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a package that is used offline but then you can host online web surveys it generates. I think it's a really nice product. It uses Perl and flat files on the back end. It could use some updating but overall it works very nicely. It also supports complex surveying techniques such as conjoint analysis.

[Sawtooth SSI Web](http://www.sawtoothsoftware.com/) ($)

Answer (score 0):

I personally have not had a lot of luck with this software. The CATI surveying is nice but the web surveying portion of it needs a lot of work. It's really not very customizable at all. Hopefully they will improve it in the future.

[Voxco Interviewer Web](http://voxco.com/) ($$$)

Answer (score 0):

I've used [FormAssembly](http://www3.formassembly.com/) in the past which works quite well.  They've got both free and pay as you go plans too, so it's also a cost effective option in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the open source PHP web application: [Limesurvey](http://www.limesurvey.org/)

Answer (score 0):

http://obsurvey.com is one, and it's free.

- It is very very easy to use
- You can format all of the text
  with basic formatting
- You can insert pictures everywhere-
- It has braching
- It has reporting and filtering of
  responses
- You can download charts as images
- You can download entire reports as
  PDF
- You can share live reports, and
  shared reports can even be filtered
  and PDF's can be downloaded

---

Answer (score 0):

http://www.doodle.com/ is another free service.

You can create a poll for many different purposes (simple yes|no voting, or finding the best timeslot for many people by vote), or yes|no|maybe and many variations.

Registration is purely optional: the poll and the participants can be anonymous. Or you can register for some ease of use if you use it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I developed the app:

http://www.lagunasurvey.com/ is another option.

It is certainly a true web app, and you can embed images and videos in the questionnaire. There is a free version and there are never any recurring costs.
There's a PDF User's manual under 'Documentation' for those who prefer that. Or just go to the site and test it out.